# How to set QGIS 2.14 on OS X to use GRASS 7

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-plugins, grass-7.0

My current QGIS installation (2.14) on OS X 10.11 is set up to work with GRASS 6.4.4.  I am guessing this is the default GRASS version that comes preinstalled with the QGIS package maintained by William Kyngesburye.

However, I have GRASS 7.0 installed on my system (from Michael Barton's packages), and would like to set my QGIS to work with GRASS 7.  In addition, I would like the GRASS plugin for QGIS to use GRASS 7.  As you can see in the attached screenshot, the GRASS version the plugin is using is 6.4.4 (2014).

[image]

I tried to set the "Custom" installation path to my GRASS 7 installation, but the plugin tells me that particular GRASS installation is not valid.

P.S.: GRASS 7 and QGIS are working fine on my OS X 10.11 installation, as I have disabled SIP.

Answer (score 2):

1. For Processing, I give the answer in [Bug report #14339: Mac OS X: GRASS GIS 7.0 correction](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/14339)

   The problem is in lines 257-259 of the file /Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/plugins/processing/algs/grass7/Grass7Utils.py

   `if isMac() and os.path.exists(Grass7Utils.grassPath() + os.sep + 'grass70.sh'):
               command = Grass7Utils.grassPath() + os.sep + 'grass70.sh ' \
                   + Grass7Utils.grassMapsetFolder() + '/PERMANENT'`

   and is in the GRASS version of M.Barton the file involved is

   `/Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS/grass.sh`

   So simply correct the script replacing grass70.sh by grass.sh

   `if isMac() and os.path.exists(Grass7Utils.grassPath() + os.sep + '*grass.sh*'):
               command = Grass7Utils.grassPath() + os.sep + '*grass.sh* ' \
                   + Grass7Utils.grassMapsetFolder() + '/PERMANENT'`
2. For the plugin, it is another question that I have not yet looked for